# How do i change the root folder that psexec.exe uses?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt, psexec

Im trying to run a batch file on remote computer using psexec.exe
My code is;

```
psexec.exe \\192.168.13.187 -u Administrator -p default -d -i c:\temp\abc.bat
```

But when i execute this on command prompt, it connects to remote server's system32 folder then start the batch file.. Problem is that batch file has some CALL method in it (like CALL XXX.BAT) (XXX.BAT file is in the same folder.) Since psexec.exe uses system32 folder as root path, after running c:\temp\abc.bat file successfully, it could not CALL the other batch file. throwing 'could not find the file specified'..

My question is; how do i use the remote C:\temp\ folder as a root path after connecting the remote computer ?

Thanks for help in advance !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-w` [switch](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) Luke.

`-w directory Set the working directory of the process (relative to the remote computer).`